# How to Read Parquet Records From InputStream

Tags: parquet

I have a file encrypted parquet data and it is read as an Inputstream. I want to extract individual parquet records from this Inputstream.Is there any way to do this? In avro it is possible with DatumReader.I am not supposed to  write my data on disk in between.

Comment: Did you figure a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Download tmp File

```
ParquetReader<Group> reader = ParquetReader.builder(new GroupReadSupport(),new Path(file.getAbsolutePath()))
                            .withConf(conf)
                            .build();
```